# How do I initialize the first row in a 2D array?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, initialization

I want a 13 row array with 4 columns and I want the first row to have the characters "C", "D", "H", and "S", but that's not what I'm getting. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char a[13][4] = {"C", "D", "H", "S"};
  int i, j, k;

  for (i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
      for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
          printf("%c ", a[i][j]);
        }
      printf("\n");
    }

  return 0;
}
```

This is what it's outputting:

```
C
D
H
S
```

When it should be

```
C D H S
```

I've tried Googling tutorials for how to initialize multidimensional arrays, and I thought I was doing it right, but I must be doing something wrong that I'm unable to see for some reason.

Comment: Characters are `'A'`. `"A"` is a string.

Comment: `char a[13][4] = {{'C', 'D', 'H', 'S'}, };` this also initialises all other elements to `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration

```
char a[13][4] = {"C", "D", "H", "S"};
```

initializes first four rows of array `a` with four strings `"C", "D", "H"` and  `"S"`. If you want to initialize only first row with characters `'C', 'D', 'H'` and `'s'` then it should be like

```
char a[13][4] = {{'C', 'D', 'H', 'S'}};
```

Other elements of array will be initialized to `'\0'` character.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use character constants rather than string constants.  Change the double quotes to single quotes:

```
char a[13][4] = {'C', 'D', 'H', 'S'};
```

Comment: Right, although it looks like they're being displayed as single characters in the sample code.